# Бронювання чи резервування

Tags: вживання-слів

Як правильно резервувати чи бронювати квитки на потяг?

З СУМ-11

> ***[Резервувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/rezervuvaty)*** ую, уєш, недок. і док., перех. Залишати що-небудь у резерві.
>
> ***[Бронювати](http://sum.in.ua/s/bronjuvaty)*** *рідко.* Надавати кому-небудь право розпоряджатися, володіти ким-, чим-небудь; закріпляти за ким-,
>   чим-небудь.

На сайтах з продажу квитків можна зустріти обидва варіанти (бронювання/резервування), але як буде правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Згідно до [Словника синонімів Караванського](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53408/272242.html) та інформації з цього [сайту](https://www.dictionaries24.com/uk/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) дані два дієслова є синонімами і можливий як перший, так і другий варіанти.